# Using flutter ImagePickerWeb IN WEB are getting image .how to update the IMAGE TO API

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Here is the code i'm using in flutter web

```dart
 var mediaData = await ImagePickerWeb.getImageInfo;

 String mimeType = mime(Path.basename(mediaData.fileName));
 html.File mediaFile =
   html.File(mediaData.data, mediaData.fileName, {'type': mimeType});

 if (mediaFile != null) {
   setState(() {
     _cloudFile = mediaFile;
     _fileBytes = mediaData.data;
     _imageWidget = Image.memory(mediaData.data);

     print('print'+_imageWidget.toString());

   });
 }
```

getting image - (print) like this:

```sh
Image(image: MemoryImage(Uint8List#6b8a3, scale: 1), frameBuilder: null, loadingBuilder: null, alignment: Alignment.center, this.excludeFromSemantics: false, filterQuality: low)
```

how to convert above image send  to api